# How to edit previous listView instead of add a new one?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have one icon `button` and one `listView` in Activity A.

Icon button-----> intent to B, return value to A, add to new list

ListView click--> intent to B, return changed value back to listView

I use `mClickedPosition=-1;` to verify whether icon is clicked or listView,**but  it still add to new list even the listView is clicked.**

**Activity A**

```
      @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
             switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.addDetails:
                    mClickedPosition=-1; // if icon is clicked
                    View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.addDetails);
                    PopupMenu po = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView); //for drop-down menu
                    po.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_details, po.getMenu());
                    po.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if ("Add Work Details".equals(item.getTitle())) 
                    {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), B.class);  // go to Activity B
                       startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
                     }
                        return true;
                      }
                        });
                     po.show(); //showing popup menu
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

            }

   listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { // if listView is clicked
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                mClickedPosition=position;
                Object o = listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                SearchResults fullObject = (SearchResults) o;
                String temp = fullObject.getDescription();
                String Project=fullObject.getProject();
                String [] ReceiveProject=Project.split(":");
                String[] ReceiveDescription = temp.split(":");
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(), B.class);
                i.putExtra("ReceiveProject", ReceiveProject[1].trim());
                i.putExtra("ReceiveDescription", ReceiveDescription[1]);
                startActivityForResult(i,PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
            ReceiveProject = data.getStringExtra("Project");
            ReceiveDescription = data.getStringExtra("Description");
            if(mClickedPosition==-1) {  // if icon clicked
                MyCustomBaseAdapter objMyCustomBaseAdapter = (MyCustomBaseAdapter) listview.getAdapter();
                objMyCustomBaseAdapter.addNewItem(ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, ReceiveProgress, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut); // add list
            }
            else
            {
                // change the current list
            }

        }
```

**MyCustomBaseAdapter**

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   // for ListView in Activity A


        private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results) {
            searchArrayList = results;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return searchArrayList.size();
        }



        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return searchArrayList.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

       public void addNewItem(String P,String D,int Per,String I,String O)
      {
        SearchResults obj=new SearchResults();
        obj.setProject(" Project/Service/Training : "+P);
        obj.setDescription(" Work Description : " + D);
        searchArrayList.add(obj);
        this. notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtProject= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListProject);
                holder.txtDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListDescription);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.txtProject.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getProject());
            holder.txtDescription.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getDescription());
            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtProject;
            TextView txtDescription;

        }
    }
```

Comment: So your clicking on menu option but its adding new list

Comment: @Clairvoyant Nope. It should add a new list if menu option is clicked. The problem now is it add new list although listView clicked.

Comment: So what you want to achieve is to add the item to previous list if user clicked listview and if clicked on menu option then make new list

Comment: which i think is already being generated

Comment: @Clairvoyant if listView get clicked,it will goes to B and finally return the changed value back to Activity A listView. But now it add a new list instead of update. I'm not sure whether the problem come in this  `if(mClickedPosition==-1) {  // if icon clicked
                MyCustomBaseAdapter objMyCustomBaseAdapter = (MyCustomBaseAdapter) listview.getAdapter();
                objMyCustomBaseAdapter.addNewItem(ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, ReceiveProgress, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut); // add list
            }
            else
            {
                // update
            }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96577/discussion-between-john-and-clairvoyant).

Comment: finally the list not added after add  `mClickedPosition=position;` in `onItemClick`. Now I want to return the edited value to ListView A and updated it.

Comment: Why can't you pass different result code to differentiate the Menu item Vs List item? startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_CODE_ADD); startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_CODE_EDIT);

Comment: I use `mClickedPosition` to check and it works now. Now I don't know how to return the edited value to A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.get the object of particular potion where you click

```
 SearchResults obj=searchArrayList.get(postion);
```

2.now set the value like this way

```
 obj.setProject(" Project/Service/Training : "+P);
 obj.setDescription(" Work Description : " + D);
```

3.finally notify the adapter.

```
this. notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: This is in MyCustomBaseAdapter ?

Comment: i know but when you adding new item you are creating a new object of SearchReasult but now you can get the object and set the property and remove line searchArrayList.add(obj);

Comment: Thanks! I create another method in the if-else block  `else
            {
                objMyCustomBaseAdapter=(MyCustomBaseAdapter)listview.getAdapter();
                objMyCustomBaseAdapter.changeItem(mClickedPosition,ReceiveProject,ReceiveDescription,ReceiveProgress,ReceiveTimeIn,ReceiveTimeOut);

            }`

Comment: , then in `MyCustomBaseAdapter` write    `public void changeItem(int m,String P,String D)
    {
        SearchResults obj=new SearchResults();
        obj.setProject(" Project/Service/Training : "+P);
        obj.setDescription(" Work Description : " + D);
        searchArrayList.set(m,obj);
        this. notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`.....It works